# Cut big mesh (plane) in quadratic parts

Tags: export

I am working on a game-engine and the time has come to model a simple map. I thought, since i already use blender for models, why not for the map, since creating a world-editor can be time-consuming. The problem is, my engine expects the world to be in quadratic chunks of equal size. I'd like to model the map as a big plane with structures on-top in Blender and afterwards, cut the whole scene with plane and structures in equal quads to export them individually. Is this possible?

Example:
[image: World]

I'd need the whole terrain-plane to get split at the red lines **and** the little house, so every part of the house is in the corresponding chunk when i export the chunks.

Alternatively, when i create multiple equal-sized quadratic planes, to somehow *glue* one edge of one plane to another edge of another plane, so i neither get holes in between, nor get overlapping faces?

Comment: for a few cuts you could try the knife tool, a simple grid as reference, straight cuts

Comment: You can try to use some kind of wireframe (plane with deleted face and enlargened by Array) and cut your original plane with Knife Project (first plane as cutter)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To do this first join all your objects into one if they aren't already by selecting them all and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.  Then create another grid object consisting of **just edges** which you will use to slice up the map.

[image]

Select the grid *and then* the terrain (in that order), enter edit mode, go to top view (<kbd>numpad 7</kbd>), make sure you are in orthographic mode (<kbd>numpad 5</kbd> to toggle), then use the *knife project* tool found in the toolbar.  Make sure *cut through* is checked after you do so.

[image]

Your terrain will then be sliced up based on the grid object's edges.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot, however, if i merge all meshes to one big mesh, wouldn't this mess up my UV-coordinates? Now that i think about this, it's really bad to build the objects into the map directly... I think it'll be better if i build *only* the terrain in blender and then use some other technique to place objects like houses and trees.

Comment: @tkausl  No, it shouldn't mess with the UVs.  You can separate them when you are done if you need to using [P] > *loose parts*.

Comment: Oh thats good. I'll see how this works, thanks.