# How to cut mesh in blocks of 1m³?

Tags: modeling

I have a big 3D mesh and I want to split or cut through it every 1 meter in all directions. For example:

If we have a perfect cube 10x10x10 → result will be in 1000 1 m³ cubes.

Is there a tool that does that in an easy/automatic way?

I tried this, but it offers weird cube-like results - it definitely does not work as intended.

[How can I evenly split a cube?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/171017/how-can-i-evenly-split-a-cube)

Comment: will be two aspects here: the accuracy of boolean operations (may fail) and the volume aspect: do you need blocks to be exactly 1m3 (for instance). Is your mesh cubic, other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using the boolean modifier:

Beforehand, for the boolean to work, make sure your original model has no holes.

You can fix it yourself manually, or use an automatic remesh like the modifier or the sculpt mode's voxel remesh in the sidebar:
[image: voxel remesh]

Also, make sure its scale is applied via <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> >> Apply Scale.

- add a cube, in the sidebar, set its dimension to 1:1:1 meters.
- Apply the scale via <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> >> Apply Scale
- (optional): for visibility's sake, go in *Properties editor* > *Object tab* > *Viewport display*, set *Display As* : *Bounds*.
- Add an Array modifier, change the relative offset so that the new cubes have a small spacing (like 1.001, it's required for the boolean to work)
- Hit <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> twice while hovering the modifier with your cursor so to duplicate it twice, change the direction on the new modifiers to cover all three axes. Add as many repetitions needed to cover your original model with cubes.
- add a boolean modifier to your original model, set it to Intersect.

[image: result boolean]

If you want each cube to be its own object:

- Hit <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> on the boolean modifier to apply it
- Select your original model, then switch to edit mode with <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>
- select all with <kbd>A</kbd> and hit <kbd>P</kbd> > *Seperate by loose parts*.
- Back in object mode, select all the parts, <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> > *Set Origin* > *Origin to geometry*.

[image: final result]